# unable to resolve "requests". IntelliSense may be missing for this module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code: `import requests` 
I get this error under requests:

> unable to resolve "requests". IntelliSense may be missing for this module.

What is causing this error and how can it be fixed? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install the requests package first.

Simply run `pip install requests` in your terminal. Here's the [requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/).